# Change locale in android app (onto Hindi)

Tags: android, locale, hindi

Creating multi languages support for the app with possibility to change language in App settings.

As for now everything works fine for English, Spanish, Franch, Russian languages,
but doesn't work for Hindi and Chineese.

1) I specify the language name in original language 
but in the app instead of हिन्दी I can see "Hindi".

\res\values-hi\arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="languages">
        <item name="english">English</item>
        <item name="russian">Русский</item>
        <item name="spanish">Espagnol</item>
        <item name="russian">Français</item>
        <item name="chineese">中国</item>
        <item name="hindi">हिन्दी</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="languagesValues">
         <item name="english">en</item>
        <item name="russian">ru</item>
        <item name="spanish">es</item>
        <item name="russian">fr</item>
        <item name="chineese">zh-CN</item>
        <item name="hindi">hi</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

2) End after selecting "Hindi" - actually default (English) is being selected.
\res\values-hi\strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">लकी बीनने</string>
    <string name="score">0000</string>
    <string name="settings">सेटिंग</string>
    <string name="start_button">प्रारंभ</string>
    <string name="about_button">के बारे में</string>
    <string name="about">लियोनिद द्वारा बनाया गया</string>
    <string name="feedback">प्रतिक्रिया भेजें </string>
    <string name="high_score">उच्च स्कोर के</string>
    <string name="score_set">स्कोर निर्धारित किया गया है \r\nमें:</string>
    <string name="game_over">खेल खत्म</string>
```

....

Saving locale in Preferences.

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {

    Locale myLocale;
    static boolean localeChanged;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


        // language changing
        Preference langPreference = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(
                "language");
        langPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(languageChangeListener);
    }

    Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener languageChangeListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

            switch (newValue.toString()) {
            case "en":
                setLocale("en");
                break;

            case "ru":
                setLocale("ru");
                break;

            case "fr":
                setLocale("fr");
                break;

            case "es":
                setLocale("es");
                break;

            case "zh-CN":
                setLocale("zh-CN");
                break;

            case "hi":
                setLocale("hi");
                break;

            }

            localeChanged = true;
            return true;
        }
    };

    // * manually changing locale/
    public void setLocale(String lang) {
        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        finish();
    }
```

What is wrong? Is something wrong in my code, or in my device?

Comment: Further, in short: you should put the locale change code just above setContentView in your onCreate call back (it does not appear you have used it anywhere to set a layout for your activity). It helps the system choose your locale based string resources appropriately, and based on the locale, you can choose font appropriately, and apply on setFontFace.

Comment: Also please specify the make and model of your phone, as to why values-hi is not taken, even when you restart the phone or application, also see the comment above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the device. Also, please check whether your device supports `Hindi` and `Chinese` languages by going to `Settings` --> `Language & input`.

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena I completely agree with your answer. But the solution to the problem completely depends on the requirement. The developer may have some different requirement like only support those languages which are available in the device. In that case, we no need to maintain different fonts for each language. Just we need to query available locale(supported languages) and show options to select the language. If we have strings.xml maintained for that language it will show respected language otherwise it shows default language...cntd

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena..cntd...So which solution to follow completely depends on the requirement. So it is up to the developer which method he wants to follow. And further, I don't want to argue why my answer is correct. Thank you. :)

Comment: See, my answer is protected by a counter question "what if?". What if there is no language support for Chinese, Spanish, and Hindi in the same device. In older devices, I was never able to see Hindi characters at all. So when I implemented the solution below, it worked. In many of the tutorial, blogs, you do not find a clause that you should protect fall backs in your locale settings using fonts assets, so it is a general view that it won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

**I. First thing first:**

Your post has lots of logical and spelling mistakes. `Lint` will report errors and warnings for such, and code will not compile.

***Please see the corrections:***

Creating multi languages support for the app with possibility to change language in App settings.

As for now everything works fine for English, Spanish, `French`, Russian languages,
but doesn't work for Hindi and `Chinese`.

1) I specify the language name in original language 
but in the app instead of हिन्दी I can see "Hindi".

\res\values-hi\arrays.xml

```
<string-array name="languages">
    <item name="english">English</item>
    <item name="russian">Русский</item>
    <item name="spanish">Espagnol</item>
    <item name="french">Français</item>
    <item name="chinese">中国</item>
    <item name="hindi">हिन्दी</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="languagesValues">
     <item name="english">en</item>
    <item name="russian">ru</item>
    <item name="spanish">es</item>
    <item name="french">fr</item>
    <item name="chinese">zh-CN</item>
    <item name="hindi">hi</item>
</string-array>
```

> **[COMMENTS]**
>
> 1. Spelling mistakes: in the words **chinese**, **french**.
> 2. Logical mistake: repetition in the key **russian**, in both the arrays, where on the second repeat, it should be **french**.

**II. Improvements for @Chandrakanth's answer:**

It depends on the device, and your device seems to be **old** one, while your code is correct. Giving you the reasons why:

***Beginning with my answer,*** I want to quote from your question:

```
As for now everything works fine for English, Spanish, French, Russian    
languages, but doesn't work for Hindi and Chinese.
```

When you are using Chinese and Hindi, you are using following locales, as from your string resources:

```
<item name="chineese">zh-CN</item>
<item name="hindi">hi</item>
```

Please refactor it to:

```
<item name="chinese">zh</item>
<item name="hindi">hi</item>
```

So you should be using the values folders as:

```
values-zh and values-hi
```

If the above is correct then your application is not accepting or recognizing `values-zh` and `values-hi` in some **old** device.

1. Please share your device make, manufacturer and model, so that more
   investigations can be done.
2. Your code is OK, hence you can test your application in any other
       and newer device.
3. Please call the method where it changes the locale, just before
       calling `"setContentView"` inside `"onCreate"` call back.
4. Maybe you can check whether your device supports Hindi and Chinese
       language by going `Settings --> Language & input`.

> I have devices that don't have `Hindi` and `Chinese` in the device
>   settings, but still the locales `hi` and `zh` are recognized within the
>   application, though I have to install corresponding fonts to prevent
>   the fallback.

Please note that `Hindi` and `Chinese` are locales from different time zones, so most likely, they can not be found in the same devices settings.

Please see that your code is working on other **new** devices. If not, then you have to follow steps below. There are some basic understandings first:

***Firstly***, if you change `locale` in your `device settings`, it should have no effect on your `application level locale settings`. That is, if your `device locale` is set to `Spanish`, and your `Application level locale` preference is set to `Hindi`, `Hindi` should continue to show on every `fragment/activity` of your `application` if each one of these components are have the strings in them `localized`. Now if you change your `locale` from `Spanish` to `Chinese`, and your `application` or device is restarted, since `zh` is stored in your preferences, your method changes the locale to `Chinese`, on `Application load` and it continues to show text in `Chinese`.

***Secondly***, if your `language` depends upon `font` for example: since you have `English`, `Hindi` and `Chinese` locale support in your application, you have to have all `TTF fonts` in your `asset folder` and apply the `Font-face` to `TextView`, `EditText`, `Radio Buttons`, `Check Box`, `Spinners` etc. appropriately, when you change the language from your `application settings`. Here `Hindi`, and `Chinese` locales need `TTF` fonts to be there for each, in `assets` folder and has to be used in every `component's` `font-face` as mentioned above.

***Thirdly, and most importantly***, the best place to change your locale is just before `setContentView(layout_id)` of an `activity` is called in `onCreate(Bundle restoreState)` method. Therefore as soon as `locale` is changed, you have to send the control back to your `dashboard/home` screen so as to immediately see the effect.

Please see [Android get hosting Activity from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51077569/787399)

You can also see [How to use font assets using XML resources, in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource)

and [Using styles for your components in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource)

Happy Coding :-)